# TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index' when exporting individual excel row to json file with pandas

Tags: python, json

I have a spreadsheet with 10 rows for example, and want to export each row to an individual JSON file name row number.json (aka row 0 would be "0.json". However I get this error and am not sure what I could be doing wrong. Code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from pandas import read_excel

df = pd.read_excel("/fullpath/excel.xlsx", index=[0, 10], columns=['A']) 

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    with open((str([index]) + ".json"), "w") as f:
        f.write(row.to_string(row))
```

If I don't include the index, then I get a list of more than 10 rows all containing the info from row 0.

Edit:

I have since tweaked the code and tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from pandas import read_excel

df = pd.read_excel("/fullpath/excel.xlsx") 

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row.to_json(str(index)+'.json')
```

Which gave me multiple json files that all had the first row's info.  It seems to be getting closer.  Any idea how each files could reflect the next row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

observation, in code `df = pd.read_excel("/fullpath/excel.xlsx", index=[0, 10], columns=['A'])`  index and columns have no significance.

if you just want each row as json, you can use something like following and it will create json files in the same folder where script is.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    #got the row and then write the row
    row.to_json(str(index)+'.json')# method from https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've updated the post with an edit that uses this code, but gets multiple files with the first row's info (doesn't move on to second row's info).  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: pls paste some rows of your excel as this should work unless data issue.